# Объект deferred (Область применения)

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Привет.
Интересует где можно применять этот объект?
Объект deferred используется в обработчиках AJAX.
Как я понял его можно использовать для создание своих обработчиков AJAX на отслеживание результата последовательности AJAX-запросов:

```
var newDef = $.when($.get("test1.php"), $.get("test2.php"));
// установим обработчики выполнения newDef
newDef.done(function(){
  alert("Успешно выполнены 2 ajax-запроса");
}).fail(function(){
  alert("При выполнении одного из ajax-запросов произошла ошибка");
});
```

Где еще этот объект  может быть полезен?При работе с обычными функциями(не AJAX) его видимо не применяют?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну почему же, тот же $('...').animate() — возвращает $.Deferred, можно даже сделать вот так:

http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/Uxjhf/

```
$.when(
   $.get('/user/123'),
   $.get('/settings/'),
   $('#bar').animate({ width: '100%' })
).then(function (){
    // функция будет выполнена, после завершения ajaх
    // запросов и анимации
});

// или
function myConfirm(msg){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var $el = $('<div>'+
                '<div>'+msg+'</div>'+
                '<button class="yes">Yes</button> or '+
                '<button class="no">no</button>'+
                '</div>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .on('click', '.yes', dfd.resolve)
        .on('click', '.no', dfd.reject)
    ;
    dfd.always(function (){
        $el.hide('slow');
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}

myConfirm("Deffered")
  .done(function (){ console.log("YES"); })
  .fail(function (){ console.log("NO"); })
;
```

P.S. Ну и на хабре полно статей по этой теме.